# `return $this;` design pattern or anti-pattern?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, anti-patterns

I've seen many times Zend Framework using `return $this;` <strike>pattern</strike> style
 - and from my point of view:

- Pro: seems its quite not bad <strike>pattern</strike> style for chaining many actions on the same object and making your code shorter.
- Con: code looks a bit weird when you see that object returns itself in the method, which does something else (e.g. setter for some property)

Is it really good <strike>pattern</strike> practice or maybe an anti-<strike>pattern</strike>practice?

**EDIT:** well it was a little too much from my side to call it "pattern", thanks everyone for pointing me to right direction!

Comment: See Martin Fowler's article on [fluent interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html). I've never seen it as an antipattern. It works very well for many things. jQuery is another prominent fluent interface.

Comment: it's just а coding style and kind of syntax sugar, not a pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Returning `this` allows you to chain calls and set values. It is very useful for configuring some object (see [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)). You can express very easily what you want (and you can use different return types to achieve what you want).

Answer (score 8):

I've found method chaining to be useful in circumstances where it makes sense; a domain specific language, for example:

```
$query->select('*')->from('users')->where(array('user_id' => 1, 'verified' => 1));
```

The thing is, these methods would only be returning `void` anyway and so the `return $this` merely functions as a short hand version of writing:

```
$query->select('*'); $query->from('users'); $query->where(...);
```

We're still going to be calling the `toSQL()` or `execute()` method to make use of the data we've populated our object with.

In my opinion it is **not** an anti-pattern and can function as a legitimate, sensible, method of object population in the right circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean "good practice or bad practice", here's my take:

On the plus side, you get some syntactic sugar.

On the down side, you give up meaningful return values in favor of chainability. Which is not really feasible because eventually you will have to have methods which return something other than the base object, so you end up with some methods which are chainable and some which are not (users of your classes get to have fun guessing which ones are which.)

Or you go full hog and make all of them chainable no matter what, but then you find yourself in ridiculous situations such as returning a fake "empty" object for the sake of preserving the chain, which object needs to be tested for some obscure property to determine if it's a "real" one or just a link in the chain.

The classical example is jQuery, which exhibits all the symptoms: the base object attempts to be the sole basic unit of data throughout the code (everything returns a jQuery object); fake object testing (`if (obj.length)`); plus the self-contradiction where it still needs to break chainability for methods like `getAttribute()` that return string.

IMHO, it's an awful mess to make of things just for the sake of that bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: Side note: this approach led to unnatural, bad practices when using jQuery. Eg. you go looking under #foo for elements with .bar, but you don't find any, or don't even find #foo. Most of the time this means you have a big problem, they are most likely supposed to be there. The cases where you don't care if they are or not are much rarer. Yet jQuery encourages you to dismiss the fact #foo or .bar are missing and lets you happily chain methods that will accomplish nothing, with no warning. This turns things on their head, it takes a much smaller use case and makes it the norm.

Comment: I think your spot on. Perhaps you can have the best of both worlds by separating the chainable methods from the non-chainable ones with different classes as I try to demonstrate here: http://blog.programster.org/fluent-interface/

Answer (score 3):

This is called Fluent Interface, i don't think this is a pattern but better a way to implements function to reduce amount of code and improve readibility.

I let you read the Wikipedia Page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Answer (score 3):

It is not exclusively PHP/Zend Framework doing this, as there are many other programming languages that use the fluent interface. I certainly think it comes in handy and that using the fluent interface is a good way of coding. Although sometimes codes looks weird, doesn't mean it is wrong and I don't think you can place this under con to be honest.

In the end the programmer only sees that he gets the same object back, not how it looks inside the code of the fluent interface class. I think the biggest pro in the fluent interface is the readability of the code. If you want to hear a con then debugging a fluent chain is one.

- [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)