# PHP method return this, effect on performance?

Tags: php

How does it affect performance by making sure that all my setters return `$this`? To allow for chain calls similar to jQuery coding standards.

E.g:

```
public function setEnabled(){
    $_enabled = true;
    return $this;
}
```

I found this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138758/return-this-design-pattern-or-anti-pattern) with no reference to the performance side, surley there is a negative

Comment: Would you rather re reference the object for every setMethod? This spares code, who cares it's impact, it has to be better than clogging up the calling script.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: i did some benchmarks on it, returning $this instead of returning void seems to be about 17 nanoseconds slower on my i7-6700 in power-saving mode on battery on a laptop with PHP 7.1.16, benchmark code can be found here: https://github.com/Znote/POTCP/commit/10cd616ffb8257216a8ede8fbe5ce625899536b9  (i would post this as an answer but it's closed..)

Answer (score 3):

No significant performance impact. Objects are not cloned.

Comment: Worth noting it's considered a bad practice for other reasons. (Chaining methods leads to bad readability).

Comment: Disagreed. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference unless you specifically clone them (in php 5 anyway). I don't see any performance impact by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

NO the another question answer everything, in your code sample your Function will always true, and could be chain if you want

Answer (score 0):

PHP `return null;` is the same as `return;` which is the same as not returning anything at all. Either way, something is being returned, it may as well be the objects reference to itself.

Comment: and yet, in my tests, `return $this;` is about 17 nanoseconds slower than `return;` in php 7.1.16 on i7-6700 - benchmarking code: https://github.com/Znote/POTCP/commit/10cd616ffb8257216a8ede8fbe5ce625899536b9

Answer (score 0):

Most every line of code comes with a performance hit. But is that not the point of writing that line of code

Your question is very vague and depends on a few factors. The size object being returned, how it is being received, and the calculations made on `$this` before it is being returned.

Usually there is no issues with returning $this but it is all a question of judgement. If $this contains a huge data array, you can figure it will use more memory and processing time than in your example.

Comment: It's just a reference though, not the object itself. It doesn't matter the size until it's used. Which is irrelevant.