# how to call values in my oop class

Tags: php, oop

I am converting my procedural php project to OOP. I stuck on one problem.
What is the best way of retrieving table data?

Passing the id with constructor

```
new Rate(new Currency($currencyId), $amount);
```

or first setting the id and calling getId() method?

```
$currency = (new Currency())->setId($currencyId);
new Rate($currency->getId(), $amount)
```

Comment: Why would `->setId()` return an object?

Comment: @Jack all methods returning void should return $this; in php to be able to combine function calls of objects, Zend Framework makes very much and good use of it

Comment: @DanFromGermany IMO, that's a retarded idea, no offense.

Comment: @DanFromGermany , method's name should describe what it does. As you might notice, it was not called `setIdAndGetThisInstance()`.

Comment: its VERY common and useful in php... what should setId return? Its a void function. Look at Iterator classes: Iterator->next() gives you an object, Iterator->last() gives you last Object,.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138758/return-this-design-pattern-or-anti-pattern

Comment: Well .. `next()` also is not a **setter**. It is there to return the next value (as the name for the method suggests). And it returns an instance that is not an `Iterator`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany `Iterator::next()` returns the next element, not the iterator itself.

Comment: ok, bad example. I don't want to encourage discussion here, but what about chaining stters: `$person->setId(1)->setName('peter')->setLastSeen(time());`

Comment: `$person->setId_and_getPerson(1)->setName_and_getPerson('peter')->setLastSeen_and_getPerson(time());` .. fixed that for you

Answer (score 2):

The `Rate` object shouldn't care about what `$currencyId` is, rather the only thing it should know is that there's a currency:

```
$rate = new Rate(new Currency($currencyId), $amount);
```

If you want to prevent too many `Currency` objects from being instantiated, you could introduce a mapper:

```
$mapper = new CurrencyMapper();
$rate = new Rate($mapper->getCurrencyWithId($currencyId), $amount);
```

*It should be noted that when doing this all objects must be immutable, according to the rules of [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).*

Comment: @hakre Thanks for reminding me that the objects must be immutable when you use flyweight ;-)

Comment: No biggie, btw I like that pattern. It's very useful to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Ask a question on OOP design and you'll get 100 different answers. There are many different design patterns that will accomplish the same thing.

It is hard to say since we dont see your full design, however given your 2 examples, I would go with the first one.

Comment: To agree with Kris' answer, your second example would be the same as `new Rate($currencyId, $amount);` so your first example is way better, making use of dependency injection design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the viewpoint of readability and the number of calls made I'd go with the first one.  The second one makes two separate calls (one to the constructor and another one to set `$currencyId`).